# meaning of "a state of sight"

Tags: meaning

A [series of video](https://www.eyeporter.com/) tutorials uses a phrase "A State of Sight" everywhere, what does that mean?

> Watch this episode of **A State of Sight** with Isaac Porter, MD to learn more about LASIK, SMILE and PRK. Please post below if you have any questions about laser eye surgery.

I googled that phrase and got none explanation about it. Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good catch!  I have never seen this idiom either.  I have sent a message to the ophthalmologist's website to ask for a clarification as to intended meaning.  Will get back to you if they respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contact with Dr. Porter's office to request their definition of "A State of Sight."  This was the part of their response as to meaning:

> Our video blog is called "A State of Sight" because the videos give information that is considered up to date, in regards to refractive or corrective vision procedures...so, you could say "**state**" is used as a term to represent *the way things currently are* at the moment, which is of course in regards to the corrective vision and refractive procedures our office performs, hence the word "sight."

So, the definition of "state" in this instance is a noun of condition:

> **State**: a condition or way of being that exists at a particular time

Since this specific idiom has eluded other searches, perhaps Dr. Porter created this title as a succinct description of this blog.  there are others using "state" that may help understand this better:

> State of mind; state of the nation; state of being; and so forth.